# How Can I Create A Fully Connected Line With Different Colored Segments In WPF?

Tags: wpf, polyline

Take a look at this picture:

[image: Lines]]

Notice how the line to the left has a clean corner, and the one to the right does not. Here's the XAML I used to create each:

```
<Canvas Margin="10">
    <Polyline Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Polyline.Points>
            <Point X="0" Y="0"/>
            <Point X="30" Y="50"/>
            <Point X="60" Y="0"/>
        </Polyline.Points>
    </Polyline>

    <Line X1="100" Y1="0" X2="130" Y2="50" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10"/>
    <Line X1="130" Y1="50" X2="160" Y2="0" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"/>
</Canvas>
```

Obviously the `Polyline` handles the corners easily, but it doesn't support segments with different colors, which is what I need. Creating separate lines solves this problem, but I lose the clean corners. I need to be able to create a line with the corners of line 1, but the colors of line 2.

My actual application is a line graph, so these lines are created dynamically and could have dozens of segments each with an angle ranging from 0 to 180 degrees.

The only solution I have come across is to use a [`LinearGradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush) with `Polyline.Stroke`, and put in gradient stops where the corners should be. But considering the length of the line and each segment are totally variable and the gradient stops seem to be measured in percentages (from 0 at one end to 1 at the other) it just seems like it would be a pain to calculate and comes off as an over-complicated solution. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the start and end caps of the Lines' stroke to Round:

```
<Line X1="100" Y1="0" X2="130" Y2="50" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10"
      StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
<Line X1="130" Y1="50" X2="160" Y2="0" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"
      StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
```